# Join all rows in DataFrame B to each row in DataFrame A pandas, merge indices into multindex

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two DataFrames which I want to combine completely, meaning for each row in A, all rows in B are joined. No matching on any index or column needs to be performed.

DataFrame A:

```
idx | A
  0 | foo
  1 | bar
```

DataFrame B:

```
idx | A
  0 | alpha
  1 | beta
```

Result in:

DataFrame AB

```
idxA idxB | A_left | A_right
   0    0 | foo    | alpha
        1 | foo    | beta
   1    0 | bar    | alpha
        1 | bar    | beta
```

Join and merge always expect a index or column to merge on. The cartesian product throws away the index, but I also want to combine the indices as in the example above.

Comment: I've added two options for you. Take a look at both of them. At least one should be helpful.

Comment: Did you try `df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1)` That is the first option given in both questions.

Comment: cartesian product was apparently the word I was looking for. Apparently there isn't a clean method. Thanks coldspeed !

Comment: But now the actual indices are not combined! How can I create a multi-index to match the original two indices?

Comment: It's also hackish but you can reset the index before merging and set the index again: `df1.reset_index().assign(key=1).merge(df2.reset_index().assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1).set_index(['idx_x', 'idx_y'])`